# Hidden mechanics in DW8?

Tags: dynasty-warriors-8

In Dynasty Warriors 8 for PC, what are the details on the hidden mechanics? For example:

- Are there better or more item drops on harder difficulties?
- Does combo'ing a dead leader give better item drops the longer the combo?

What are the details on the above, and what other hidden mechanics are there?

From [this forum post](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/730572-dynasty-warriors-8-xtreme-legends-complete-edition/68881467) "From what I've seen doing them from beginner to hard mode there is no increase in material drop rates".

Can anyone confirm anything one way or another?

Comment: Based on every other Dynasty Warriors game, the first one is true.  Not sure about the second; sounds like a rumor more than something valid.  Do you have a source for the second question?

Comment: @Frank http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps3/606303-dynasty-warriors-7/answers?qid=269450 "If you kill them with the right number of combo hits or more"